# RESTKit - get image file from server

Tags: image, afnetworking, restkit-0.20

I'm using RESTKit in my app, and I need to send a get request which its answer is a png file. Is that possible?

I know that in the new AFNetworking there's a way to do it. But RESTKit includes an older version if AFNetworking that I'm not sure how to do it in.

I need to add to my header Authorization username and password.
I do this with

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com"]];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:name password:password];
```

but now I don't know how to perform the GET request.

Comment: What did you try? An image is just data. You should be using AFN, not RK for that as you can't apply mappings to the image data.

Answer (score 0):

`AFHTTPClient` has a method `getPath:parameters:success:failure:` that you can use. You can call this method directly on the client you use with RestKit object manager.

You should really consider using `SDWebImage` though, for specialist image management, including caching.

Comment: I'm trying this method on the `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:nil path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"profile-images/%@.png", user.name] parameters:queryParams success:nil failure:nil]`. and I get this `error:"Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got image/png"` so it still expects json. how can I avoid this?

Comment: You should not be using the object manager. Use the HTTP client, or preferably SDWebImage instead.

Answer (score 0):

why not return a URL to the PNG if possible rather than sending the binary? Of course if this PNG is rendered on the fly you may not have a choice.

Comment: I don't understand exactly. I want the image file, doesn't it mean the server needs to return the image file?

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. You already have the URL because the image is downloaded from that URL...

Comment: yeah i should've added this as a comment. my bad.

i supposed this was a web service that returns more than just an image. in that case seeing as the image binary would usually be the largest bit of data in the REST response in many cases it would be preferable to return a URL to the image so that it may be loaded separately from the rest of response. like how a browser (typically) loads images in connections separate from markup.

then load loading the image in a typical HTTP get is easy. (authenticating with a header token passed in the now text-only REST response)